# why javascript not wait for and of forEach and execute next line

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, reactjs, es6-promise

when I create my api in nodejs and trying to pushing mongoose return count to new created array, it's not wait for the forEach and execute json.res() and giving null response. when I use 
**setTimeout()** then it's giving proper result.

```js
let newcategories = [];
let service = 0;
const categories = await Category.find({}, '_id name');
categories.forEach(async (category) => {

service = await Service.count({category: category});

newcategories.push({ count:service });
console.log('newcategories is -- ', newcategories);

});  /* while executing this forEach it's not wait and execute res.json..*/


console.log('result --- ',result);
console.log('out newcategories is -- ', newcategories);
res.json({status: 200, data: newcategories});
```

Comment: Well, you cannot await the forEach, but the callback function is marked as `async` (so it will automatically return a `Promise`). So the `forEach` is long done before all your awaits are ready. Just change the `forEach` into a `for let category of categories` and await inside the `for..of` block

Comment: yeah it's working fine...........thank you sooo much :)

Comment: for (let category of categories) {
            service = await Service.count({category: category});

            newcategories.push({
                _id: category._id,
                name: category.name,
                count: service
            });
            
        }

Comment: you can use `reduce` to run this in series: `categories.reduce(async (previous, category) => { await previous; service = await Service.count... }, null);`

Answer (score 7):

You need to use map instead of forEach, to collect the awaits and wait for them to complete. Edit: Or you can use `for..of` which is pretty neat (thanks other ppl)!

```js
const categories = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

function getNextCategory(oldCategory) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(String.fromCharCode(oldCategory.charCodeAt(0)+1));
    }, 1000);
  });
}

async function blah() {
  const categoryPromises = categories.map(getNextCategory);

  const nextCategories = await Promise.all(categoryPromises);

  console.log(nextCategories);
}

blah();

async function blah2() {
  const nextCategories = [];

  for (const category of categories) {
    nextCategories.push(await getNextCategory(category));
  };

  console.log(nextCategories);
}


blah2();
```

Comment: ... or just do a "plain-old"  `for..of` loop if you want to do serial requests.

Comment: Yeah I didn't actually know about for..of working for that before this so that's cool

Answer (score 7):

So the problem you have is that `async` marked functions will return a promise per default, but that the `Array.prototype.forEach` method doesn't care about the result type of your callback function, it is just executing an action.

Inside your `async` function, it will properly `await` your responses and fill up your new categories, but the `forEach` loop on categories will be long gone.

You could either choose to convert your statements into a [`for .. of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop, or you could use `map` and then `await Promise.all( mapped )`

The for..of loop would be like this

```
for (let category of categories) {
  service = await Service.count({category: category});

  newcategories.push({ count:service });
  console.log('newcategories is -- ', newcategories);
}
```

the map version would look like this

```
await Promise.all( categories.map(async (category) => {
  service = await Service.count({category: category});

  newcategories.push({ count:service });
  console.log('newcategories is -- ', newcategories);
}));
```

The second version simply works because [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) will only resolve once all promises have completed, and the map will return a potentially unresolved promise for each category